# For will not iterate through entire list in Python

Tags: python

so I'm learning Python and having trouble with this small program I've designed to try and take my Codecademy skills further.

```
car_models = ["Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Aston Martin", "BMW"]
bad_cars = ["Toyota", "Mazda", "Ford", "Hyundai"]

for gcar, bcar in zip(car_models, bad_cars):
    ask = input("What is your favorite car brand? ")
    if ask == gcar:
        print("Yes!")
    elif ask == bcar:
        print("Ew!")
    else:
        print("The model is not listed")
    break
```

When I run this, it will only pop up with an answer if the model is the first one on the list, otherwise, it just tells you that the model is not listed even though it is.

Comment: `break` breaks out of the for loop. So as soon as you hit the end of the loop the first time, you break out of the loop.

Comment: Well, the logic of your code is what it is. Which part of its behaviour do you find confusing?

Comment: I don't think you understand how the loop is working. The variables you are iterating with move to the next value in the list at the end of each loop iteration, but since you break at the end your loop only runs once so you only iterate through the first index.

Comment: Why are you asking inside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

The **break** statement is the mistake, you must finishes the loop only when you find the object

Edited, thanks to @PM 2Ring

```
ask = input("What is your favorite car brand? ")
for gcar, bcar in zip(car_models, bad_cars):

    if ask == gcar:
        print("Yes!")
        break here
    elif ask == bcar:
        print("Ew!")
        break here
```

besides you may want to have a variable "found" to know if your models is in the lists.

**Possible Solution**

you can check if an object is in a list using *obj in list* so you could have done this:

```
ask = input("What is your favorite car brand? ")

if ask in car_models:
    print("Yes!")
elif ask in bad_cars:
    print("Ew!")
else:
    print("The model is not listed")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why do you have `break here` ? Did you mean `break #here`? Also, why do you have the `input()` call inside that `for` loop?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, input should be outside and the *here* is just a reference, I set my attention in the **Possible Solution** because I think it is a better approach

Answer (score 1):

Your question should maybe have been asked at [Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of here at Stack Overflow, but let me give you a run through of what you have actually coded.

```
car_models = ["Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Aston Martin", "BMW", "Opel"]
bad_cars = ["Toyota", "Mazda", "Ford", "Hyundai"]
```

This creates two separate lists, one of `car_models` (aka good cars) and one of `bad_cars`.

```
for gcar, bcar in zip(car_models, bad_cars):
```

First of you are creating linked tuples between the good and the bad cars. I.e. The `Ferrari` is linked to the `Toyota`, the `Lamborghini` is linked to the `Mazda`, and so on. Then you create a loop where you dissect the tuples you've just created, and for each iteration you store the good and bad car in `gcar` and `bcar`.

```
    ask = input("What is your favorite car brand? ")
```

Then within the loop, you think you ask for your favorite car brand, and store it `ask`. But what you actually do here is ask for input, and then evaluate it as python code, see [input](//docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input). (I.e. to use as is, you would have to enter `"Ferrari"` to avoid a `NameError` exception)

```
    if ask == gcar:
        print("Yes!")
    elif ask == bcar:
        print("Ew!")
    else:
        print("The model is not listed")
```

Then you test if the car just inputted matches the current iteration of `gcar` or `bcar`, and print a message if it matches. This code does **not** test against the list of cars, only the current iteration.

```
    break
```

Then after testing in the first iteration, you break out of the loop.

### Possible solution

Depending on what your main purpose, there are two slightly different fixes. Do you want to keep on asking for new car models, until they get tired, or do you want to just ask once?

Before tackling that issue, try the following code to see what your for loop produces (I've added the `Opel`, and it disappears as the other other list isn't long enough):

```
car_models = ["Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Aston Martin", "BMW", "Opel"]
bad_cars = ["Toyota", "Mazda", "Ford", "Hyundai"]

for gcar, bcar in zip(car_models, bad_cars):
    print('gcar = {}, bcar = {}'.format(gcar,bcar))
```

Assuming you want to ask multiple times, you could do like the following:

```
car_models = ["Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Aston Martin", "BMW", "Opel"]
bad_cars = ["Toyota", "Mazda", "Ford", "Hyundai"]

while True:
    ask = raw_input("What is your favorite car brand? ")
    if ask in car_models:
        print("Yes!")
    elif ask in bad_cars:
        print("Ew!")
    else:
        print("The model is not listed")
        break
```

Notice the change to using `raw_input`, and the `while True:` to keep on asking until you give a car model not listed. And notice the extra indentation of the `break` so that it is only executed when you list a car not in either list.

This could give the following 'dialog':

```
What is your favorite car brand? Ferrari
Yes!
What is your favorite car brand? Toyota
Ew!
What is your favorite car brand? Mazda
Ew!
What is your favorite car brand? Lamborghini
Yes!
What is your favorite car brand? Saab
The model is not listed
```